# Accessing a base vector member in a derived class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I solved solved as it is written in the comment.

The problem is

```
        Base b1(2), b2(10);

    b1.print();     // 2
    b2.print();     // 10
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        b1.setN(i, (i + 1) * 20);
        b2.setN(i, (i + 1) * 10);
    }
    b1.printData();  // 20 40
    b2.printData();  // 10 20 30 40 50 0 0 0 0 0

    Derived d(5);
    d.print();      // 5
    d.printData();      // 0 0 0 0 0
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        d.setN(i, (i + 1) * 3);
    }
    d.printData();  // 3 6 9 12 15
    d.insert(99);   // "Base" class does not have "insert" method.
    d.printData();  // 3 6 9 12 15 99 -> can't solve it..!
```

so i made class Base And Derived class.

```
class Base {
    int x;
    vector<int> v1;
public:
    Base(int x) : x(x){
        vector<int>v2(x, 0);
        v1 = v2;
    }
 /* ...*/
    }
};
```

I made it up to the base, but there's something I don't know.

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(int x) : Base(x) {}
    virtual void insert(int x) {
        //How can I Access on Base?
    }
};
```

I encountered a difficulty because I didn't know how to accese vector of derived/ vector of base. How do I make it?

reading about overriding, inheritance but it was confused to me.

Comment: You used the `public` keyword when writing your code. Do you know what that means? Do you know about other keywords like 'private' and 'protected', how they work, and how to use them?

Comment: _"How can I Access on Base?"_ - you can access `Base` members from the `Derived` method `insert` as if they were part of `Derived` (and in a sense they actually are).

Comment: yeah i know, but I was taught not to use public if possible. so i had problem while not using public , using private/protect - ususally private.

Comment: Well, if you already know what `private` and `protected` keywords do, then what exactly is your question? That's all the knowledge that's required, here. If their purpose is understood, then accessing the vector in the base class from the derived class is a solved problem.

Comment: @moomalangyee If you want to acces a base class member from a derived class, you need to have it protected at least, certainly not private.